# How to Centralize Title text for Custom Action Bar through Styles.XML

Tags: android, layout, android-styles

I just created a custom action bar from my styles.xml class that shows up just the way I want it. And I have activated it from the manifest file.

```
<style name="customStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/customActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/titletextcolor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="customActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/custom</item>
    </style>
```

However, I'm trying to find a way to CENTRALIZE the title text on the action bar from the styles.xml file. Please can anyone help with how to do that.

I tried using this: `<item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>`. But it had no effect.

Most of the suggestions I've seen online requires creating a toolbar layout separately. But I've done that and Its not what I want because It requires way more code.

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know there is no easy way. By default the title follows the Material Design guidelines and is supposed to be aligned on text of the page that why it's on the left. But there is always a designer thinking Android is iOS and wants to centre the text. So if it's really what you want to do you'll have to go the hard way.

Comment: I just tried that right now, but that doesn't work unfortunately, Its centralizing something else. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a centered title in ABS (if you want to have this in the default `ActionBar`, just remove the "support" in the method names), you could just do this:

In your Activity, in your `onCreate`() method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
```

`abs_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="my Title"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now you should have an `Actionbar` with just a title. If you want to set a custom background, set it in the Layout above (but then don't forget to set `android:layout_height="match_parent"`).

or with:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage));
```